# Java Reg. Expressions for Oracle SQL data types

Tags: java, regex, string, oracle, whitelist

I'm looking to whitelist user inputs before they are entered in my `Oracle` database. I have a (sloppy) method called `cleanString(String param, String stringToClean).`

Based on the `param`, the string is cleaned with `replaceAll()` Note: there are a lot of different `Strings`

Example:

```
if(param.equals("title")){
            retVal =stringToClean.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z-&,\\s]", "");
```

Instead of going through every single possibility, are there `Java` regexs out there that pertain to `data_types` in an `Oracle` database? I have been missing inputs here and there because the regexs are not perfect.

i.e.

a regex that matches **varchar2(255byte)**, one that matches **varchar(20 byte)**, **numbers**, **dates**, etc. etc.

Comment: Why? Just use prepared statements.

Comment: @BoristheSpider in what way? Can you give an example? This is simply a Utility class that handles the whitelisting

Comment: @PT_C What Boris means is that white/blacklisting is the totally wrong way to solve your problem. `PreparedStatement`s take care sanitizing inputs.

Comment: @beerbajay I'm just a puppet on a string my man. I do what i'm told

Comment: Then collect what you need at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012 and build your whitelist.